# Hi! How i can write symbol & to variable in CMD ? )

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to write symbol & to variable in CMD for word is like = `adc&def`.

Comment: Could please share your code/Command which you are trying?

Comment: Have you tried the caret `^` as an escape character, like in `set a=b^&c`?

Comment: Please share more details. What keeps you from using your keyboard to type that character?

Comment: `Set "var=abc&def"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use a caret `^` to escape the character. It will work for these characters: `& < > ^ |` (You escape a caret by using a caret).
2. Use double-quotes. By using double quotes it's not necessary to escape characters (except exclamation marks when using `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

So, the final solution could be:

`set "var=abc&def"`
or `set var=abc^&def`.

Comment: Using a QUOTATION MARK is the correct way to do this. Not using a QUOTATION MARK is bad practice.